# Configure Azure Insights to NOT track my visists?

Tags: azure-application-insights

With Google Analytics you can download a program so Google knows when you go to your own site and does not track those stats but I can't find any settings for Azure Application Insights to do the same. I have been able to modify my web.config file so that the HTTP Modules are only configured when deployed to production preventing the stats from getting skewed by debugging but when I go to my live site I am not sure how to get my browsing stats to be ignored. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for that.

You can try this:

- If your application uses some authentication create telemetry initializer that would assign context.user.id (instead of telemetry initializer that AI adds for tracking anonymous users). Then in the portal you can create a chart that would filter out you as a user. You would need to save this chart in favourites so customization is saved.(http://www.apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/)
- Same idea: add some custom properties on the base of something, e.g. start collecting ip or add some query string parameters in custom properties. Then create a chart that will filter that out.